# validation for radio buttons ( at least one is checked )

Tags: reactjs

Validation of multiple radio buttons, at least one have to be check if not alert error

I have tried setting Id to the radio button and the section id, but it return me "cannot set property of 'checked' of null "

```
function validate() {
if (document.getElementById('course').checked) {
alert("option selected!");
}
else {
    alert("No option selected!");
    }
};

<Section id='cbutton'>

<Radio                                                  
id="course"
name="CompSci"
value={values.CompSci}
options={[
{ label: "Major", value: "MAJOR" },
{ label: "Minor", value: "MINOR" }]
onChange={onChange}
inputSize={FIELD_SIZE.LARGE}
label="CompSci"
error={errors.CompSci}
/>

<Radio                                                  
id="course"
name="ChemEngineering"
value={values.ChemEngineering}
options={[
{ label: "Major", value: "MAJOR" },
{ label: "Minor", value: "MINOR" }]
onChange={onChange}
inputSize={FIELD_SIZE.LARGE}
label="ChemEngineering"
error={errors.ChemEngineering}
/>
```

Managed to validate the part where none of radio buttons is checked it will prompt a alert, but after I tried to check one it still prompt the alert.

Comment: this might be because your Radio component might not be adding id passed to it in the input element inside it...

Answer (score 1):

What is your onChange method and your state? Are the radio elements controlled or uncontrolled? If it's controlled you should be using handleChange to update the state and the checked value. For which you need a "checked" attribute. [Here's an example of Radio buttons with React.](https://codepen.io/sam_saama/pen/jJBbdx)

```
const App = () => {
  const [selectedVal, setselectedVal] = React.useState('First')

  const handleChange = event => {
    console.log(event.target.value, event.target.checked)
    setselectedVal(event.target.value)
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <label htmlFor='smallest'>
        <input
          type='radio'
          value='First'
          checked={selectedVal === 'First'}
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
        <span>First</span>
      </label>
      <label htmlFor='largest'>
        <input
          type='radio'
          value='Second'
          id='largest'
          checked={selectedVal === 'Second'}
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
        <span>Second</span>
      </label>
      <div>You've selected {selectedVal}!</div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to validate value based on name.id is unique across the DOM.

```
function validate() {
    var radios = document.getElementsByName("course");
    var formValid = false;

    var i = 0;
    while (!formValid && i < radios.length) {
        if (radios[i].checked) formValid = true;
        i++;        
    }

    if (!formValid) alert("Must check some option!");
    return formValid;
};

<Section id='cbutton'>

<Radio                                                  
name="course"
value={values.CompSci}
options={[
{ label: "Major", value: "MAJOR" },
{ label: "Minor", value: "MINOR" }]
onChange={onChange}
inputSize={FIELD_SIZE.LARGE}
label="CompSci"
error={errors.CompSci}
/>

<Radio                                                  
name="course"
value={values.ChemEngineering}
options={[
{ label: "Major", value: "MAJOR" },
{ label: "Minor", value: "MINOR" }]
onChange={onChange}
inputSize={FIELD_SIZE.LARGE}
label="ChemEngineering"
error={errors.ChemEngineering}
/>
```

Comment: When the name.id is unique across the DOM, isnt it will conflict the radio button when choose the options? for example when i click on the major of CompSci, it will affect the options of ChemEngineering as well

Comment: Definitely its effects. Radio buttons are used when there is a list of two or more options that are mutually exclusive and the user must select exactly one choice. In other words, clicking a non-selected radio button will deselect whatever other button was previously selected in the list.
If you want to choose both you need to go with Checkbox

Comment: I meant by, when i click on the major of the CompSci selection, the chemEngineering button will be affected as well